# how to rebuild kernel modules after a linux-image kernel installation?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, apt, kernel

I have a default installation of Ubuntu 18.04.5, it comes with Linux Kernel 5.4.0. After that installation I found out I need a specific kernel version: 5.3.0, so I've installed it using apt:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-image-5.3.0-69-generic linux-headers-5.3.0-69-generic
```

Now when I choose this kernel over the default on grub menu, I'm unable to see ttyUSB* devices: their driver is missing

```
$ sudo modprobe usbserial
modprobe: FATAL: Module usbserial not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-69-generic
```

The default installation of 5.4.0 has those drivers, but it seems like if manually installed, the new kernel version doesn't rebuild the modules.

My question is - how do I rebuild this module with this kernel version?

Some interesting thing that I found is that on an unattended-upgrade of the kernel: a minor version advance, dkms seem to do that automatically. This didn't happen for the manual 'apt' that I did:

```
$ uname -a
Linux s8b 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsmod | grep ftdi
ftdi_sio               61440  0
usbserial              49152  1 ftdi_sio
$ locate ftdi_sio
/lib/modules/5.4.0-64-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.ko
/lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.ko
```

Comment: this and other modules are normally in linux-modules-extra-kernel-version-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-5.3.0-69-generic linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-69-generic
```

Reboot.